# Rails server won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to setup Ruby on Rails for the past 2 days now. I had them running at one stage but broke it. I have gone through re-installing Ruby and Rails via RVM and I am attempting to get going on the tutorial I have been working on. The problem I have is that when I run the command 'rails s' within the Rails app directory I get the following error message:

```
    Exiting
/home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gemsin my terminal /ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `const_get'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `session_store'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:172:in `block in default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `tap'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `app'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/hugo/rails_projects/web_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hugo/rails_projects/web_app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/hugo/rails_projects/web_app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/hugo/rails_projects/web_app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/hugo/rails_projects/web_app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /home/hugo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can somebody explain to me this error please? I am getting very tired. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line has the following error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
```

RVM needs to know how to get to your openssl library.

See http://beginrescueend.com/packages/openssl/ for more information on setting up openssl with RVM.

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I'll give your solution a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You compiled ruby without the openssl dependencies. Do

```
rvm requirements
```

(or `rvm notes` if you are using an older version of rvm that doesn't have `rvm requirements`)
and see what you need to install in your system (typically these are apt-get commands if you are running ubuntu for example), and then recompile your ruby installation
by

```
rvm remove 1.9.2
rvm install 1.9.2
```